# Abstract method with variable arguments

Tags: java

accumulating totals in CheckingAccount class is not outputting correct total

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I know I am not passing the value correctly, but can not figure it out and have worked many hours trying to resolve it, but nothing works.

```
abstract class BankAccount {
   double balance = 0.0;
   double totalBalance;
   double deposit;

   public void setBalance(double balance) {
      this.balance = balance;
   }


   public double getBalance(double balance) {
       return this.balance;  
   }

   public void setTotalBalance(double totalBalance) {
       this.totalBalance = totalBalance;
   }

   public double getTotalBalance(double totalBalance) {
      return deposit + balance;  
   }

   public void setDeposit(double deposit) {
      this.deposit = deposit;
   }

   public double getDeposit(double deposit) {
      return this.deposit;  
   }

   public abstract void debitAccount();
   public abstract void creditAccount();          
   }


import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BankAccountTestDrive {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccountArray = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

   BankAccount checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount();
   BankAccount autoLoan = new AutoLoan();
   autoLoan.creditAccount();

   checkingAccount.creditAccount();

   checkingAccount.setBalance(62.00);   
      checkingAccount.setDeposit(6.00);
      checkingAccount.setDeposit(10.00);        
      checkingAccount.setDeposit(4.00); 

      bankAccountArray.add(checkingAccount); 

     autoLoan.setBalance(30.00);
     autoLoan.setBalance(2000.00);
     bankAccountArray.add(autoLoan);

    for (BankAccount bankaccount : bankAccountArray) {
     bankaccount.creditAccount();                        
    }
    System.out.println("Checkiing Balance " + checkingAccount.getBalance(0));
    System.out.println("Auto loan Balance " + autoLoan.getBalance(0) + "\n");
    System.out.println("Total accounts:     " + bankAccountArray.size());
    }
}



class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
    public void creditAccount() {       
       balance = deposit += balance;
    }

    @Override
    public void debitAccount() {
       balance -= balance;      
    }
}
```

each deposit needs to be added to the balance to accumulate a total for checkingAccount and the same for AutoLoan.

expected output:
Checkiing Balance  70.0
Auto loan Balance  1970.0

Total accounts:     2

Comment: Can you post the code of `AutoLoan` class too?

Comment: You should write information like your current output and expected output in your post - you can edit it.

Comment: Well, your deposits **replace** one another. You don't **add** them together.

Comment: The logic in the methods of CheckingAccount almost certainly is not doing what you intended.  `balance -= balance` always sets the balance to zero.  And while I don’t feel like taking the time to analyze what `balance = deposit += balance` actually does, I strongly suspect you do not want a `+=` assignment in the middle of your expression.  Addition is done with `+`, not `+=`.

Comment: @michalk - I figured out how to edit my post and updated it. Thanks!

Comment: @RealSkeptic I realize my deposits are replacing one another, which is why I posted in this forum. I don't understand what I am doing wrong so I am asking for help. If your intent was just to point out the obvious then why did you comment?